# Mentions of River Iravati(ऐरावती) which is from Myanmar(Burma)?

Tags: scripture, rivers

Are there any mentions of Iravati River(irawaddy River in Burmese) in our Hindu scriptures? It is the blood line of Myanmar.

We(Hindus) of Myanmar call it Iravati Ganga.